# Getting tips transactions hashes

Tags: transaction, pyota

I want to get the current tip transactions; 
trying to get the tips addresses using pyota api works fine:

```
tips = api.get_tips()
addr_tips = tips['hashes']
```

However trying to find transactions from the above addresses:

```
hashes = api.find_transactions(addresses=addr_tips)
```

gives empty answer. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Tips are transactions, not addresses

`api.getTips()` already returns the **tips (= transactions)**, not addresses.
`tips['hashes']` are the transaction hashes of the tips.

So when you do

```
hashes = api.find_transactions(addresses=addr_tips)
```

You are giving `find_transactions()` a bunch of transaction hashes as addresses. The node then looks up all those transaction hashes (thinking they are addresses because they have the same length as addresses).
Since there are no transactions using those "*addresses*", you get an empty result.

---

## Bug

You were probably confused because of [this](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/issues/130). I was too but I figured out that the `Addresses` are actually `TransactionHashes` because

1. Tips are transactions, therefore `get_tips()` should return transactions.
2. The result addresses all ended with 4 nines. `TransactionHashes` always end with 4 nines for example:

---

```
[Address(b'DGUAYXNWFMZCQOIJBGQGHAUTDZRXOONMIPRHS9KOIGL99OPLAECWGA9MCUAMHFWQJBVJLYGTRRDGA9999'), Address(b'LKNKVDENAJLYPZYEBEEEKGQSGQRHRYZOGZBX9EHGIDLAYPFNXFRPOYXPJKBOMOBPMV9BKDCVKHBPZ9999'), Address(b'VZ9GJYNIYLSNJYFIHCTAFWDCEPYIAOHZPWNUSACVABUDALIJVV9WDEQBFMJEZQHUYCJEFFQNVWKEZ9999'), Address(b'KWAUXSLHYL99HTLOLDXJ9IAMPVEKSJRCTNYUXNIVUZRMEED9PXYKYMICIDTIU9GAUANYMMCHO99MZ9999'), Address(b'TXGGPSGSLEULGFTWEBDNLRBMK9HEXGTVXGSHLXMGSMJGVREYZDFSO9TUDAGOAITAA9NPP9TBELJUA9999'), Address(b'QIUE9NIXHOXWEDZYBKCT9LBPIYVPEJAQIJKYCGPXTICMFIKAXEKRZEJQKSNFEQJZWDLHFDXB9FCJ99999'), Address(b'OGWFDEDC9YQJCJQUSUAGIHUBODOVVCRITJG9RWAFTXHZMTAVJWUPHZWPRWICRIUIKAOMXQWHAKMA99999'), Address(b'MHXVLYBKI9NXVMGASRCSVTGTWPRS9VEN9GAGNFRVOTFHBCXLQUSVDIQHMNHYHZBTZZCSLGHSEDYOA9999'), Address(b'JTG9EEXQFAAI9TGGQ99JA9LMTKWG9FDBOECR9EIAIJEIHGPOEZKSNGDZBPTVEQZKEAPAVVHNMYHBA9999'), ...
```

---

## Solution

To achieve what you want, this is enough:

```
tips = api.get_tips()
hashes = tips['hashes']
```